# Software like xclip that comes standard on just about all Linux Distros with X?

Tags: linux, xorg, clipboard

I have an application that needs to access the clipboard on *nix OSs but I do not have access to the x event loop because of how it works. Therefore I need to send a command to another application to perform copy paste of strings. I was going to use xclip until I found out it is not standard with every Linux distro. Is there an application that comes standard on every (or almost every) Linux distro that can do copy paste of strings?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no tool guaranteed to be on every Linux distro.  xclip, or xsel are very common.  If you really need it to be present, why not simply request that it be installed?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which tool is most common, but in addition to `xclip` there also is a tool called `xsel` (MacOS has `pbcopy`). Then there also is uclip, however it is not going to be as widespread and [it have some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741129/what-is-the-minimum-amount-of-tweaking-needed-to-get-qclipboardsettext-to-wo). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740109/unable-to-copy-fast-a-file-to-clipboard-in-a-linux-computer/740139).